# Kubernetes Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get

Tags: rhel, kubernetes

I have a K8S cluster, 2 servers, 1 master, 1 worker and everything works fine.

- K8S version: 1.19.2
- Calico: curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -O // with the modify CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
- Metallb: 0.9.3 installed as recomended at https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/

Cluster deploy:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr "10.11.0.0/16" --upload-certs
```

cluster:

```
ardc01k8s-master01.nps.local   Ready    master   41m   v1.19.2   10.10.80.1    <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)   4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.13
ardc01k8s-wrk01.nps.local      Ready    <none>   34m   v1.19.2   10.10.80.11   <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)   4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.13
```

When I deploy the cluster with HA (for multiple masters) Metallb fails and cant read confimaps so see the ips it can assing.

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "10.10.80.10:6443" --pod-network-cidr "10.11.0.0/16" --upload-certs
```

metallb controller error:

```
E1009 19:34:56.370850       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-   78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.12.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.12.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I1009 19:34:56.371672       1 trace.go:81] Trace[1783558010]: "Reflector pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98 ListAndWatch" (started: 2020-10-09 19:34:26.371367929 +0000 UTC m=+1612.080726327) (total time: 30.000286335s):
Trace[1783558010]: [30.000286335s] [30.000286335s] END
```

metallb cant read the configmap and the services stuck in <Pending> state.

All servers are fresh RHEL installs and I made snapshots to rollback.
Any ideas?

Comment: The IP address on that error message is 10.12.0.1, and the error is an IO timeout. Is that a valid endpoint? Is there a firewall before it, which is possibly blocking the connection?

Comment: yes, its the cluster service ip so there is now firewall

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a timeout connecting to the Kube API server, it means that there is a problem with the routing somewhere.

Before installing metallb, verify that you can reach the Kube API internally.

Get cluster ip of kubernetes service

```
kubectl get service kubernetes
```

Verify internal connectivity to Kube API server using the cluster ip

```
kubectl run -i -t --attach test --restart=Never --image=ubuntu:20.04 -- bash
apt update -y && apt install -y curl
curl https://10.12.0.1:443
```

Make sure you can reach the Kube API server on each master using it's physical ip on port 6443

```
curl https://10.10.80.10:6443
```

For HA, you need an external load balancer configured before initializing your kubernetes cluster. This LB listens on port 443 that sends request to each master on port 6443. Ideally you would have two load balancers sharing a VIP.

You can use haproxy with a simple config like so

```
listen kubernetes
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server kube-master-1 10.10.80.10:6443
    server kube-master-2 10.10.80.11:6443
    server kube-master-3 10.10.80.12:6443
```

Now create your kube cluster with kubeadm but point to the load balancer's ip (VIP) and use port 443

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "MY_VIP:443" --pod-network-cidr "10.11.0.0/16" --upload-certs
```

Make sure you can reach the Kube API server both internally and externally, then install metallb

You will have to handle HA for etcd as well, check out the docs for different options

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/master/docs/ha-considerations.md

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was RHEL8 with nftables and docker, it seems that it crashes.
I resolved the issue using RHEL7.8 which has legacy iptables, not the best solution but I need it now. Thanks!